# select options are not being shown using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, combobox

I am trying to show the names of few detectors in a combobox using d3.js. I used the following code to show the data.

```
d3.csv("Results_New.txt", function(data) {

//var data = d3.csv.parseRows(datatext);
d3.select("#road").selectAll("option")
.data(data).enter().append("option").text(function(d){return d.detector-id;}).attr("value",function(d){return d.detector-id;});
```

But the values are not being shown in the output combobox. Rather the combox options are showing blank space. Can anyone give me the idea how can the values be shown? Is it mandatory to put the combobox within a SVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your column in your csv file is named "detector-id"?

`d.detector-id` is not valid.  That's translated as object variable d with property detector minus variable id.

Use `return d["detector-id"];` instead.

Here's working [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/GjtHM433Iulif0jhXtup?p=preview).

> Is it mandatory to put the combobox within a SVG?

You actually aren't putting a combobox box in SVG.  What I think you mean is "is it mandatory to build the combobox with d3?"  The answer is no.